# Update Back Button Text While Scrolling ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am looking for a way to update the Back Button text in a navigation controller for Swift. Mainly I want to have a large title navbar that shows the full title of the previous screen - then when the user scrolls and the navbar collapses to the regular sized navbar, I want to change the Back Button text to "Back". I am able to change the back button text correctly - but it does not update the navbar to show the new button text.

I tried using the UIScrollViewDelegate method: scrollViewDidScroll which lets me update the title at the right time, but no luck on the back button.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! > CGFloat(59.5) {
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Large Title"
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Long Title Here"
    } else {
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Small Title"
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Back"
    }
}
```

Comment: put a break point in else and check if you code is going into the else.

Comment: It is, and it updates the correct titles - just doesn't display (update screen with them once changed).

Comment: Still unable to solve. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` of the previous `viewController` not the one on the top of the navigation stack.

```
if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
  if viewControllers.count > 1 {
    let previousViewController = viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2]
    previousViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "desired title"
  }
}
```

Comment: The Back button text needs to change when the navbar collapses - the title changes when the collapse happens and back when it expands - the issue is only with the back button text not updating (although the title string does - just doesn't appear on screen to update).

Comment: I know, your code to change the title is correct, but your line to change the back text isn't, that's why I only mentioned the back text code, if I am getting something wrong, please post a video to explain :)

Comment: This doesn't work - the best approach to what you are saying is to change in the previous viewController in the prepare(for segue:) method. My situation needs the button to update on the current view - which the title attribute does - just doesn't display on-screen with the new title string.